# Cloudflare - Ineligible for SSL

Tags: cloudflare

I can not use ssl on cloudflare!

on `Crypto` tab, show `Ineligible for SSL` but my site is on cloudflare and is active.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I try to talk cloudflare support center.

they answer this:

We are not able to provide SSL for `.ir` domains at this time.

My apologies for any inconvenience this may cause.

Comment: That really has to do with US sanctions more so than anything.

Comment: It's cruel for people :(

Comment: And now those sanctions are back; or they've never been lifted. :(

Comment: Shameless US sanctions.

Answer (score 3):

As someone has mentioned already this can partially be due to some TLDs not being supported by CloudFlare (perhaps as they cannot find certificate authorities to sign them). One example of this is .ir.

One other reason for this is that you could have your domain set-up via a CNAME record, this is if your hosting provider is a CloudFlare Partner and they have set-up CloudFlare for you. In order to overcome this you need to upgrade to a pro account before you can use SSL.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too! Cloudflare didn't let me apply certbot(letsencrypt) on my `.ir` domain.
I logged in to cloudflare and paused it, and then certbot work perfect on my domain!
[screen-shut of cloudflare disabling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc3Qt.png)

hope this help.

Comment: I think cloudflare have some problems. Because all sites uses this, have problem to load .js and .css files now!!

Comment: @mghhgm I should notice that after applying ssl on `.ir` domain, I resume cloudflare but my site did't load after that! So I paused cloudflare to load my site again by ssl!

Answer (score 1):

There's certain tlds and words Comodo won't sign for them. I wonder when they'll switch to letsencrypt.